# Get all files out of a lot of folders?

Tags: python, windows, file, directory

I want to get all files from Folders.

I restored my hard disk and got a 1000 Folders each with 500 Files, i want to get them out of the foldes into a singel folder so i can run python to sort the files.

Sadly i didn't find anything what works so i hope someone can help me.

So i tryed one thing:

Runing this code in the Windows Console:

```
pushd C:\Users\KroherL\Downloads
   for /r %%a in (*.?*) do (
       MOVE "%%a" "C:\Users\KroherL\Music\new%%~nxa"
   )
popd
```

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: What is that command? What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

This works on Windows:

- make text file with the following single line

```sh
for /r %%i in (*.*) do xcopy /Y "%%i" c:\cumulFolder
```

(where `c:\cumulFolder` is the destination folder where you'll find your files all together)
save the text file as `.bat` (e.g `RecurseCopy.bat`)

- copy this file in the main folder where you want to search and copy files into subfolders too.
- doubleclick on your `.bat` file